# Laravel sort with eager loading

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

In Laravel 4.2, we have a User:: model, which has Message::(s). Every Message has a Sender:: which is not a normal user. I want to sort the result dynamically by columns in Sender:: model.

I have tried this but it doesn't work:

```
$this->sort->dir = 'asc';
$this->sort->by = 'sender_name';

$result = User::find(1)->messages()->with(array('sender' => function($query){
        $query->orderBy($this->sort->by , $this->sort->dir );
}))->paginate(10);
```

User Class:

```
class User extends Eloquent{
....
public function messages(){
     return $this->hasMany('Message' , 'toid' , 'id' );
}
```

Message Class:

```
class Message extends Eloquent{
....
public function sender(){
     return $this->hasOne('Sender' , 'sender_id' , 'fromid' );
}
```

Message Table:

```
id, toid, fromid, text
```

Sender Tabele:

```
sender_id, sender_name, ...
```

User Table:

```
id,name,....
```

I can't change the table structure as it is related to another application. Does anybody know what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

you are almost near, just you need little modification, pass variable in closure and add get() at the end of `orderBY` to get records in your desire orders.

```
$by = 'sender_name';
$dir= 'asc';

$result = User::find(1)
          ->messages()
          ->with(array('sender' => function($query) use($by, $dir){

              $query->orderBy(by , $dir )->get();

           }))->paginate(10);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, But it doesn't work still.

Comment: Tell.me what is `sender` is it relationship?

Comment: Problem is that this doesn't sort the whole Collection, just 'sender' s are sorted with this method. So I guess I should use a join query!

Comment: yes, You have to use join else there is no way to sort parent records by children OrderBy.